# How to get the recurly subscriber uuid to local db

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1, recurly

I am using `recurly gem`. Now i am trying to do update the subscriber plan recurly. Here every subscriber have unique id. How to get that id to locally. I referred the following code.

```
subscription = Recurly::Subscription.find('44f83d7cba354d5b84812419f923ea96')
subscription.update_attributes(
:plan_code => 'silver',
:quantity  => 2,
:timeframe => 'now'
 )
```

How to get the subscriber uuid in `xml response` i.e `44f83d7cba354d5b84812419f923ea96` from recurly to local db. Help me.

Answer (score 0):

The ruby gem doesn't actually provide any ActiveRecord integration so you'd need to handle any storage yourself.